# Executing a query with string inside a function

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I have to execute the following query inside a function:

```
SELECT year FROM tbl_people WHERE personal_card = 'A5B123';
```

It returns an integer.

The problem is, I have to do the following:

```
EXECUTE 'SELECT year FROM tbl_people WHERE personal_card = 'A5B123'';
```

But it truncates the query to:

```
SELECT year FROM tbl_people WHERE personal_card
```

I tried:

```
EXECUTE "SELECT year FROM tbl_people WHERE personal_card = 'A5B123'";
```

But also fails.

How can I achieve it?

Comment: Tried `EXECUTE 'SELECT year FROM tbl_people WHERE personal_card = \'A5B123\'';`?

Comment: I tried, but it gives me syntax error.

Comment: Try using 2 `'`s like so: `EXECUTE 'SELECT year FROM tbl_people WHERE personal_card = ''A5B123''';`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Single quotes [are escaped by doubling them](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-STRINGS) in SQL:

```
EXECUTE 'SELECT year FROM tbl_people WHERE personal_card = ''A5B123''';
```

But a more convenient way to do this kind of thing in Postgres is to use [dollar quoted strings](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-DOLLAR-QUOTING):

```
EXECUTE $$SELECT year FROM tbl_people WHERE personal_card = 'A5B123'$$;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`quote_literal`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-string.html) function like this:

```
EXECUTE 'SELECT year FROM tbl_people WHERE personal_card = ' || quote_literal('A5B123');
```